# Hide and Show File Input According to Pre Selected Dropdown Value

Tags: javascript, html

I have dropdown like below

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<select name="qtype" id="edit_qtype" class="form-control">
<option value='SINGLE ANSWER'>SINGLE ANSWER</option>
<option value='MULTIPLE CHOICE'>MULTIPLE CHOICE</option>
<option value='MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH IMAGE'>MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH IMAGE</option>
<option value='MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH AUDIO'>MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH AUDIO</option>
<option value='MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH VIDEO'>MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH VIDEO</option>
<option value='TRUE OR FALSE'>TRUE OR FALSE</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Since This form is used for edit data, I am automatic selecting dropdown using data we have. Now my above three dropdown need file input like audio, video and image. So I Have all three input fields like below

```
<div class="form-group" id="imagediv" style="display:none;">
<label class="col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="image">IMAGE</small></label>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="file" id="edit_image" name="image" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" aria-required="true" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png">
        </div>
</div>
```

and two others. I am keep it hidden using style. Now When Page Loading get completed, I want show file upload section based on dropdown selected, I can not use data change function because its already get selected and We don't need change dropdown value. so I am getting confused how I can make it visible. Let me know if someone can help me for that.

I require

```
if selected value is MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH IMAGE I want show imagediv
if selected value is MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH AUDIO I want show audiodiv
if selected value is MULTIPLE CHOICE WITH VIDEO I want show videodiv
```

Thanks!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the JS code that you've tried?

Comment: If you are loading the `dropdown` on `edit` button click. You can get `selected` value within the `edit` buttons click event.